# ng-view routeprovider not working when including jquery js

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I'm developing a app based on angular js and inturn uses jquery mobile and web features.

When im linking the jquery js files the ng-view router doesnt work, but if i remove the included jquery library it works perfectly.

It would be of much help if you could say me what i have done wrong in here

This is a sample page i have designed which depicts the problem

Without including the jquery files

http://plnkr.co/edit/Yyrj0up8eywugTA3blYE

after including the jquery files

http://plnkr.co/edit/SfAEL0rWFedC49FNYUsB

For my app i need to have both versions of jquery mobile and web files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the order you are loading them in. In this order, it works:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="appController.js"></script>
```

working Plunkr here: http://plnkr.co/edit/wLLTb60Sz4ikn61wJooF?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

AngularJS includes a version of jQuery called JQLite, if you want to replace that with the full jQuery library you need to load that first before Angular.  Just move the script tags loading jQuery above the script tag that loads Angular.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding jquery first then angularjs later. I donot know why but adding jquery first works good with UI than adding jquery after angularjs.

Comment: Its because Angular includes a subset of jQuery already, if on load the Angular library sees the full jQuery version available it will use that instead else it will stick with its JQLite version.  If jQuery is loaded after Angular then Angular has already decided to use its own version.

Comment: I didnot knew that. +1 :)